# What's wrong with my mergesort implementation?

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, mergesort

On smaller lists of up to size N = ~1950 or so, I get the correct output... however, list sizes that are not much larger return an error rather than the expected result. My code:

```
def merge(left, right, aux=[]):
    if left == []:
        for x in right:
            aux.append(x)
        return aux
    elif right == []:
        for x in left:
            aux.append(x)
        return aux
    elif left[0] > right[0]:
        aux.append(right[0])
        return merge(left, right[1:], aux)
    else:
        aux.append(left[0])
        return merge(left[1:], right, aux)

def msort(values):
    size = len(values)

    if size == 1:
        return values
    else:
        mid = size/2
        return merge(msort(values[:mid]), msort(values[mid:]), [])
```

Running `msort` on these test lists give me the expected (ascending order) output:

```
val = [x for x in range(1950, 0, -1)
val = [x for x in range(4,0,-1)]
```

e.g. [1,2,3,...,1948,1949,1950] and [1,2,3,4]

However, when I run `msort` on this test case:

```
val = [x for x in range(2000,0,-1)]
```

I now receive this error (after numerous tracebacks to `merge`):

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

So my question is: What went wrong with my implementation here? I can't use it with lists of N ~ >=2000. Why?

Comment: What about `if size <= 1:`? And `list.extend(other_list)` to append a list.

Comment: That's an ... interesting ... implementation of mergesort.

Comment: `[]` cases are account for in merge, and I do not account for passing empty cases directly into `msort`.

Comment: The Problen I think is the recursive merge function. It will call itself 1000 times recursively for 2000 elements. 1000 is the maximum recursion limit set in module `sys`. Use a for loop instead.

Comment: It's wrong when called multiple times. See [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/395760)

Comment: @delnan: I thought that at first too, but ISTM `merge` is always called with a value for the `aux` argument.  It's still dangerous, but I don't think it's actually causing problems here.

Comment: That's so not merge sort... In merge sort you divide the list in two *halves*, not in head and tail!

Comment: @Bakuriu, what do you mean by head and tail? Isn't that what `msort` is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your merge function uses recursion that has a limit.

If you iterate instead of recurring you circumvent this:

```
def merge(left, right, aux=[]):
    while left and right:
        if left[0] > right[0]:
            aux.append(right.pop(0))
        else:
            aux.append(left.pop(0))
    aux.extend(right)
    aux.extend(left)
    return aux
```

This is an example of the usage:

```
>>> merge([1,3,5,7], [3,4,5,6])
[1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: oh the NONE return was a typo on my part, your code works fine, currently testing on larger list...

Comment: Yea... I guess the recursive calls were causing some nasty problems for me, ouch.... thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're doing the **merge** recursively.  As pointed out, it's fine to call `merge(msort(left),msort(right))`, but since your `merge` function actually calls itself to do the merging, you're hitting the recursion limit.

Consider calling your `merge` function on lists of length 1000.

To merge those lists, you need 2000 calls to merge (since you only add ~1 element to `aux` with each call).

Comment: Heh, I guess the answer was glaring right at me! [=, thanks for your input!

Comment: After doing some reasearch here on SO, and on other websites, it appears my main problem was my misunderstanding of python. Specifically, I was under the impression that each predecessor call to merge would be treated trivially in the sense that they would get cleared from the stack through each progression. But after a little investigation, it appears that python doesn't optimize for tail recursion, without explicitly coding this kind of behavior. Incidentally, it appears you have addressed this type of question in a past post. Perhaps, I should have worded my question differently.

Answer (score 0):

You reached the maximum recursion depth.

This means, that your function `msort` calls itself more often, than python allows this by default.

You can increase this default value with [sys.setrecursionlimit.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)

Comment: Though increasing it carries the risk of crashing the interpreter (killing the process and potentially corrupting memory, not raising a Python exception).

Comment: The problem is not the recursion limit. A correct merge sort implementation does `logn` recursive calls, hence that error should *never* happen since python lists can have at most 500 million items(and the logn of that is less than 32).

Comment: On my system, the recursionlimit (obtained with `sys.getrecursionlimit()`) is `1000`. In case of a bad implementation, this is not enough.

Comment: @Bakuriu Please note, that the OP's `merge` is also a recursive function.

Comment: increasing  sys.setrecursionlimit only delays the problem, it doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Bakuriu Wrong, 2n - 1 is the worst case number of calls

Comment: @jamylak By "number of recursive calls" I meant the height of the recursion tree, and since each call halves the size it's *definitely* `logn`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Right I misinterpreted you

Answer (score 0):

Python has a limit for recursion. You can set the maximum  (be careful ) using:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(MAXRECURSION)
```

I was able to run your list

```
val = [x for x in range(2000,0,-1)]
```

with a MAXRECURSION of 2500

Comment: And for a list that's 4000 items?